# How to read a JSON file which have size of 4 GB in python?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open("review.json",encoding="utf8",) as f:
    data = [json.loads(line) for line in f]
data
```

Data is just like:

```
[{'review_id': 'Q1sbwvVQXV2734tPgoKj4Q',
  'user_id': 'hG7b0MtEbXx5QzbzE6C_VA',
  'business_id': 'ujmEBvifdJM6h6RLv4wQIg',
  'stars': 1.0,
  'useful': 6,
  'funny': 1,
  'cool': 0,
  'text': 'Total bill for this horrible service? Over $8Gs. These crooks actually had the nerve to charge us $69 for 3 pills. I checked online the pills can be had for 19 cents EACH! Avoid Hospital ERs at all costs.',
  'date': '2013-05-07 04:34:36'},
 {'review_id': 'GJXCdrto3ASJOqKeVWPi6Q',
  'user_id': 'yXQM5uF2jS6es16SJzNHfg',
  'business_id': 'NZnhc2sEQy3RmzKTZnqtwQ',
  'stars': 5.0,
  'useful': 0,
  'funny': 0,
  'cool': 0,
```

When i run the code the whole data is not showing on the output console. I am using python 3.6. Please help

Comment: Where are you printing it to the console?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the ijson library - a module that will work with JSON as a stream, rather than as a block file.

```
import ijson
f = open("review.json")
for item in ijson.items(f, "item"):
   print str(o) + "\n"
```

Comment: It show the error c:\users\shani\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\ijson\backends\python.py in basic_parse(file, buf_size)
    190         pass
    191     else:
--> 192         raise common.JSONError('Additional data')
    193 
    194 

JSONError: Additional data

Comment: It looks like you may have a syntax/encoding error with delimiters/separators or escape sequences - make sure your key-value pairs (like "name": "Stewart") are all separated by commas and that there are curly brackets and square brackets in the correct places. The EXACT same error was mentioned in this article: https://github.com/isagalaev/ijson/issues/40